# What does 'scale' in this sentence mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

"...The relationship between nonprofits and government is a marriage that can't end in divorce. Government needs us to deliver our services, and we need government to **scale** our services to meet our mission. There's no way we can privately fundraise our way out of this..."

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: make the operation of 'services' bigger

Comment: I did look it up in the dictionary. But I'm having a hard time pinning down the meaning here

Comment: Explain what you found.

Answer (score 3):

'Scale' used here as a verb means to match the size of one thing in proportion to another. To my surprise I have not found this definition of this word after a short search; the nearest is as a noun:

> the relation between the real size of something and its size on a map, model, or diagram:

which I found at [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale).
The usage you quote is a noun-as-verb version of this definition. It's commonly used in this way in business jargon, and in computing as 'at scale' to mean that a system, especially a web-based one, will function with a high volume of users, and not just as a small demo or proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171744?rskey=DlOxde&result=10&isAdvanced=false#eid) offers some help with the verb (trans) scale :

> b. **With down**: To reduce in amount according to a fixed scale or standard. Also loosely, to reduce. Also Comb. scale-down attrib. ? orig. U.S.
>
> c. **With up**: to increase in amount or size according to a fixed scale or standard; to increase from a small scale to a larger scale. Also absol.

The examples are not up to date :

1979   Daily Tel. 19 May 2/1   The original pay claim for a 30 per cent. rise has been scaled down to 16 per cent.

1979   Sci. Amer. Jan. 45/1   Several organizations are currently scaling up from laboratory-size cells to units of demonstration size.

> d. **To measure or represent** (a quantity) in exact proportion to its absolute size or according to an arbitrary defined scale.
>
> e. **To alter** (a quantity or property) by changing the units in which it is measured; to **change the size of (a system or device) while keeping its parts in constant proportion.**

I would say that the last highlighted definition is the most relevant, here.